# "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" when adding record to Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've searched for hours for a solution to this problem but nothing I've read has helped.  I'm getting this error when trying to add this record to an Access database.  The file I'm trying to save into is named Cats.accdb, with a table named Cats.

**Table column names**:
CatId (type: text)
 CatName (text)
 Hair (text)
 Size (text)
 CareType (text)
 Notes (text)
AdoptDate (date/time general date), Weight (double), Age (integer) (I've commented any reference to these columns out in the C# code to attempt to debug with just plain old text boxes.  At first I thought it was because of something to do with using a DateTimePicker, but it still throws the error after commenting out.)

**C# code**:

```
Cat temp = new Cat(txtCatName.Text, txtHair.Text, txtSize.Text, txtCareType.Text, txtNotes.Text);

public string AddCat()
    {
        string strFeedback = "";

        string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Cats (CatName, Hair, Size, CareType, Notes) VALUES (@CatName, @Hair, @Size, @CareType, @Notes)"; 

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

        string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Data\Cats.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
        conn.ConnectionString = strConn; 

        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
        comm.CommandText = strSQL;  
        comm.Connection = conn; 
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatName", CatName); 
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hair", Hair);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", Size);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CareType", CareType);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes);
        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdoptDate", AdoptDate);
        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", Weight);
        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age);

        {
            conn.Open();
            strFeedback = comm.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString() + " record has been added successfully!";
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            strFeedback = "ERROR: " + err.Message;
        }
        return strFeedback;

lblFeedback.Text = temp.AddCat();
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: apologies, i've removed that tag.

Comment: Thank you ( @guffa specially )... I had the same problem, you guys just solved it... One of the fields that I have on the table was a reserved word (I don't know which one, so what I did was just, put brackets one every field name - one the "Insert statement"). Like this: string insertOnDB = "Insert Into [Users] ([Username],[Password],[CreatedOn],[FullName],[Gender],[AccountType],[Status])values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; Thank you, once again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Size` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266). Add brackets around the name to specify that it's an identifier:

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Cats (CatName, Hair, [Size], CareType, Notes) VALUES (@CatName, @Hair, @Size, @CareType, @Notes)";
```

Alternatively, change the field name to something that is not a keyword.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I had Name used before changing it to CatName because it was flagged as a reserved word, so I didn't even think of that one (obviously).  Your suggestion solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access OLEDB I believe you use position markers rather than parameter names.

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Cats (CatName, Hair, Size, CareType, Notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: No Access accepts the same parameters syntax used by its big cousin. (Or better, the OleDB provider doesn't care) However this doesn't mean that OleDb recognizes these names and allows you to change the order in which you supply the values

Comment: Sorry you're right. I looked at the connection string with the absence of the word "jet" without realising it has been superseded.