# Access table update fail

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I use the following code to fill a `DataGridView` from an Access Database. After a Save button is clicked if the Data Grid is updated, the Database saves the data.

The strange thing is that this works for 2 out of 3 Data Tables. For the last one it throws an exception:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

```
public Tables(string tabName)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Text = tabName;
    this.query = string.Format("SELECT *" + " FROM [{0}]", tabName);
    conn.Open();
    detailTable = new DataTable();
    string tableName = tabName;
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", tableName);
    OleDbDataAdapter detailAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
    if (detailAdapter != null)
    {
        detailAdapter.Fill(detailTable);
    }
    DataGridView.DataSource = detailTable;
    conn.Close();
}

private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
    OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
    adapter.Update(detailTable);
}
```

Even if the words are reserved keywords (although I searched them) there is no way of that to be the issue.
More information the tabName can be "Partners", "Salaries", "Descriptions" and "Accounts". It doesn't work only on "Partners".

Comment: Did you have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019828/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-when-adding-record-to-access-database

Comment: Yes, sir. To be honest I did not find any reserved word. On top of that I tried putting brackets around the table name and still get the same error, only on "Partners".

Comment: @V.Stoyanov Did you put all the information related to the exception in the question?

Comment: @mjwills Nope, sorry. It does not work only for "Partners". As for the query its value is "SELECT * FROM [Partners]"

Comment: You are **100% sure** there is a table called that? You are pointed at the right database? You've gone into Access directly and verified `SELECT * FROM [Partners]` runs successfully?

Comment: Yep, totally sure

Comment: Seems very quirky. I'd check if that tabName contains weird characters. E.g. check `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tabName)` only contains normal ASCII characters.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Everything contains normal ASCII characters. The value of tabName is determined by menustrip item click, not user input.

Comment: @V.Stoyanov Do you have more details regarding the exception?

Comment: @Kzrystof yes, that is pretty much it...

Comment: What are the column names in `Partners`?

Comment: Why do you have `this.query = ...` and also `string query =...` with different format parameters?

Comment: @mjwills Partner, PhoneNumber, Manager and E-mail

Comment: @Crowcoder well the values are the same. This is just my preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out I was wrong and I apologize for my stubbornness. The problem was in the e-mail column and I did not see why it had a problem with the dash mark.